# jQuery script not being refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been wondering why the following jquery script is not beeing run every 5 seconds.

The correct height of the DIV ".leistung" (there are multiple ".leistung" div's with different lenght of text thats why every block has to have the same height) is beeing applied on load. But the function is not beeing run every five seconds for some reason. 
Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<section class="leistung">
        <div class="leistung-image">
            <img src="http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif"/>
            <div class="leistung-image-titel">
                <span>Title</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="leistung-teaser">
        Some more text
    </div>
</section>


<script>
    var maxHeight = 0;

    window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.leistung').each(function(){
            var thisH = $(this).height();
            if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
        });
        $('.leistung').height(maxHeight);
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show more code and where you put this script.

Comment: Check the logic of your function. I don't see how it can update the height every 5 seconds.

Comment: you are right ill try something else

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP is looping using `each` and since there are no any other elements with the class name `leistung`, I don't think he wants only to take the `<section class="leistung">` element. So I assume that he want to select all the elements with name starting `leistung`.

```
<script>
    var maxHeight = 0;

    window.setInterval(function(){
        //added ^ selector here 
        $("[class^=leistung]").each(function(){
            var thisH = $(this).height();

            if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
            console.log(maxHeight);
        });
        // and here
        $("[class^=leistung]").height(maxHeight);
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you've done and why would be helpful?

Comment: right, so you've just set the time to 1 second....This solves the issue how exactly?

Comment: I assume that he want to select all the elements with name starting "leistung". so if my assumption is correct, you need to use $("[class^=leistung]") selector. sorry about the 1 second. i was testing with 1 second.

Comment: He has a class `<section class="leistung">`, so this seems an incorrect assumption to make. Why would you not include your assumption in your answer? You should read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Liam since he is looping using `each` and there is no any other elements with the class name `leistung`, I don't think he wants only to take the `<section class="leistung">` element. That is why I assume that he is trying to check all the classes starting with the name `leistung`

Comment: Ok, so say this? Your answer currently consists of a block of code, no explanation, not even a note to say what you've changed. You need to explain you answer!

Comment: @Liam I totally understand that it is my mistake that I didn't add the explanation. i apologize to you and the all the other programmers who got confused by my answer. Thank you very much for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem. I only run the fuction every 5 seconds. But when the height has been set once it will just fetch the set height again and set it again...

I will have to come up with something else to solve my problem

Comment: I do not think this question will be helpful or educate to future visitors.